# HttpClient Task fails to start

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I have some very simple code that I have been using in a windows 8 store app without any issue. However When I shared the code with windows phone app It just hangs forever. See sample below. This calls any web url and returns its source as a string. both the post and get methods hang in the same way. any help is much appreciated, Thank you.

```
    public static string GetWebSource(string Url)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        Task<HttpResponseMessage> Resp = client.GetAsync(Url);

        //code hangs on following line forever
        //Resp.status always stays at waiting for activation
        Task.WaitAll(Resp);

        if (Resp.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Task<string> response = Resp.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Task.WaitAll(response);
            return response.Result;
        }
        return "";
    }

    public static string PostWebSource(string Url, string data)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        StringContent sc = new StringContent(data);
        Task<HttpResponseMessage> Resp = client.PostAsync(Url, sc);

        //code hangs on following line forever
        //Resp.status always stays at waiting for activation
        Resp.Wait();

        if (Resp.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Task<string> response = Resp.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Task.WaitAll(response);
            return response.Result;
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using an HttpWebRequest on Windows Phone. See this link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-us/9b4c1ef2-853c-468a-bca8-97477a02583c/httpclient-for-windows-phone-8?forum=wpdevelop